# Symfony2 - Loading Doctrine fixtures for ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, entity-relationship, fixtures

I understand how to setup load fixtures for a OneToMany with the following:

`$this->addReference('category-1', $category1);`

and using it with the following:

`$blog1->setCategory($manager->merge($this->getReference('category-1')));`

**But how would you do this for a ManyToMany relationship, if the blog has 2 or more categories?**

Would you just double up the lines in the fixture so you have 2 or more ->setCategory() fields

`$blog1->setCategory($manager->merge($this->getReference('category-1')));`

`$blog1->setCategory($manager->merge($this->getReference('category-2')));`

**or use**

`$blog1->setCategory($manager->merge($this->getReference('category-1', 'category-2')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture` class and view the `->getReference()` function it will show that variable passed in for the function is for a string.

This means that the first example, calling `getReference` twice is the way it will work.

```
$blog1->setCategory($manager->merge($this->getReference('category-1')));
$blog1->setCategory($manager->merge($this->getReference('category-2')));
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming this.